# Angular 2 - Binding and Unbinding HostListener Events

Tags: javascript, angular, dom-events

I am attempting to bind and unbind a HostListener click event based on a component's input variable.

The component is a popup which has a single input called `show`. This input holds the active/inactive state of the popup. I would like to fire a click event on the entire document but only when the input `show` is set to true.

Is there a way to bind and unbind the hostlistener event inside the ngOnChanges function I have?

The current code I have:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input, ViewEncapsulation, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'custom-popup',
    templateUrl: './popup.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./popup.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class PopupComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() show: boolean = false;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }


    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
    clickHandler(targetElement) {
        // Custom code to handle click event
    }

    ngOnChanges(show: boolean) {
        if (this.show) {
            // Bind Click Event
        }
        else {
            // Unbind Click Event
        }
    }
}
```

Any assistance and insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to unbind the event and not just set a flag that determines whether to skip the rest of the handler or not? It probably wouldn't be much of a performance difference either way (AFAIK).

Comment: I tried that approach already but unfortunately this raises a problem. When I toggle the popup `show` with a click event on a separate button the HostListener click event fires. The event fires after the `show` input has changed not before.

Comment: Have you tried using a separate flag to `show` then? Set and clear that flag in the `ngOnChanges()` handler, and hopefully that means the order you want things to happen in will be enforced.

Comment: Unfortunately this method has huge performance drops. i.e. a page has 20+ popup components with hostlistener events attached.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end I implemented a solution using a service. The service handles the click events on the document and uses an observable to enable components to subscribe to the event.

The popup component subscribes to the `stateService` click observable when it is opened and unsubscribes when it is closed.

Popup Component:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input, ViewEncapsulation, HostListener} from '@angular/core';
import {StateService} from "../services/state.service";
import {Subscription} from "rxjs";  

@Component({
    selector: 'custom-popup',
    templateUrl: './popup.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./popup.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class PopupComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() show: boolean = false;

    constructor(private stateService: StateService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    ngOnChanges(show: boolean) {

        if (this.show) {

            // Timeout to ensure subscription after initial click
            setTimeout(() => {

                // Subscribe to the document click service when the input opens
                if (!this.clickSubscription || this.clickSubscription.closed) {
                    this.clickSubscription = this.stateService.documentClick$.subscribe(targetElement => {
                        // Logic for closing the popup
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        else {

            // Remove the subscription when the input closes
            if (this.clickSubscription && !this.clickSubscription.closed) {
                this.clickSubscription.unsubscribe();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

@GregL Thank you for your suggestions

Comment: This method is really an alternate to what I was hoping. So if anyone does come across a method for binding and unbinding HostListeners please share :)

Answer (score 2):

To ensure that only 1 host listener is set up when a popup is shown, introduce a new child component `PopupBody` that has the host listener on it, and an `@Output()` to pass the event back up to the `Popup` component.

Then, in your template, make the `PopupBody` component conditional using `*ngIf="show"` and it should then only bind the host listener when the popup is shown, and unbind it when the popup gets hidden.